# Laravel - Fetching selected columns in relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to fetch only selected columns using laravel relationship.
**Main tables:**

```
posts
- id
- author_id
- content
post_media
- id
- post_id
- link
- caption
```

In my laravel Post model, I've defined relationship like,

```
public function postMedia()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostMedia::class);
}
```

And while fetching data, the query is:

```
Post::select('id', 'content')
 ->with('postMedia:id,link')
 ->where('author_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
 ->paginate();
```

But the query returns empty post_media array, even after replacing `paginate()` with `get()`
I also tried,

```
Post::select('id', 'content')
 ->with(['postMedia' => function ($query) {
  $query->select('id', 'link')
 })
 ->where('author_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
 ->paginate();
```

But still didn't work. Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be selecting the key the relationship uses or it won't be able to match the records back to the parent, in this case you need to also select `post_id`, the foreign key:

```
Post::select('id', 'content')
    ->with('postMedia:id,link,post_id')
    ->where('author_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->paginate();
```

> "When using this feature, you should always include the `id` column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve."

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: This trick did work for me, except without short form like `post_media:id,post_id,link`, this one gave me an SQL error saying `unknown column post_media.post_id`. So I had to use the long-form of using the closure to select columns.

Comment: what was the name of the foreign key on post_media?

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['postMedia' => function($query) {
             return $query->select(['id', 'link']);
         }])
         ->where('author_id', auth()->user()->id)
         ->select('id', 'content')
         ->get();

dd($posts)
```

Comment: foreign_key will be automatically evaluated based on the table name. If I'm taking all values using ->with('postMedia'), it works, but it doesn't work when I try to fetch specific columns from that table.

Comment: @SwapnilBhikule Ok sure. Any error happens when try to fetch specific columns?

Comment: @SwapnilBhikule I have updated answer please check it.